# CI3.x Active Record - How to chain query with aliased fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

This is the query I am trying to build which works:

```
         select
                year(created_timestamp) as year,
                month(created_timestamp)as month,
                MONTHNAME(created_timestamp) month_name,
                count(*) total_published
                From posts
                GROUP BY year, MONTH(created_timestamp), MONTHNAME(created_timestamp)
                ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC';
```

Now I am trying to build the above query using active record as follows:

```
    $this->db->simple_query('year(created_timestamp) as year, 
    month(created_timestamp) as month, monthname(created_timestamp) as monthname, 
    COUNT(*) post_count');

     $this->db->group_by('year');
     $this->db->group_by('monthname');
     $this->db->group_by('month');
     $this->db->order_by('year', 'desc');
     $this->db->order_by('month', 'desc');       
     $this->db->from('posts');
     $query = $this->db->get();
```

Below is the error I get.  It obviously doesn't know the aliased names.  How can I get CI to recognize the aliased names?

```
Unknown column 'year' in 'order clause'

SELECT * FROM `posts` GROUP BY `year`, `monthname`, `month` ORDER BY
 `year` DESC, `month` DESC
```

## Some debugging effort produced the solution:

After much debugging, this is the solution:

```
 function blog_archive(){
    $this->db->select('year(created_timestamp) as year, month(created_timestamp) as month, monthname(created_timestamp) as monthname, COUNT(*) post_count');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->group_by('year');
    $this->db->group_by('monthname');
    $this->db->group_by('month');
    $this->db->order_by('year', 'desc');
    $this->db->order_by('month', 'desc');
    $blog_archive = $this->db->get()->result_array();;
    return $blog_archive;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 function blog_archive(){
    $this->db->select('year(created_timestamp) as year, month(created_timestamp) as month, monthname(created_timestamp) as monthname, COUNT(*) post_count');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->group_by('year');
    $this->db->group_by('monthname');
    $this->db->group_by('month');
    $this->db->order_by('year', 'desc');
    $this->db->order_by('month', 'desc');
    $blog_archive = $this->db->get()->result_array();;
    return $blog_archive;
   }
```